# Error connecting to Bluetooth device in Android Studio using Kotlin – could the UUID be the problem?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, bluetooth, uuid

Connecting to bluetooth device in android studio using kotlin. Posible UUID issue? I am trying to connect to a bluetooth device using kotlin. Every time I try to connect to device I get an error reading "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:506) ...". The error is pretty long but it points to my line on my program where it try to run socket.connect()

this is the class I use for the device thread
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private inner class ConnectThread(device: BluetoothDevice) : Thread() {

```
    private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        val my_uuidpar = UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")

        device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(my_uuidpar)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public override fun run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it otherwise slows down the connection.
        bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()

        mmSocket?.let { socket ->
            // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
            socket.connect()

            // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
            // the connection in a separate thread.
            //manageMyConnectedSocket(socket)
        }
    }

    // Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
    fun cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket?.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Could not close the client socket", e)
        }
    }
}
```

then in my on click listener for the listview I simply have
scannedDevices.onItemClickListener =
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id -> // value of item that is clicked

```
                // Toast the values
                Log.d("mac scanned",devicemap.get(position).toString())
                var connectedDevice = devicemap[position]?.let { ConnectThread(it) }
                connectedDevice?.run()
            }
```

I think this might have a problem to do with th UUID I am using I don't know how to find the correct UUID for this device. I have read the documentation and it is pretty vague on what to do. I have the MAC address of the device I want to connect to I just need to find a way to get the correct UUID.
I know there is a way to get the UUID from BlueToothDevice.uuid in kotlin but I am to confused to figue out how that works when I try to use BlueToothDevice.uuid.getParcelableExtra it throws an error as well. I do unders stand that it is an array, but even tyring to get the first element from the array and parcing that still no luck.

Comment: I have figured out a work around if anyone else has the same problem just let me know and I can help you. I was trying to connect to a raspberry pi so you would have to be doing the same thing or similar.

Comment: Feel free to [answer] your own question and mark it as solved to help other users find a solution quicker